# How does Spring's @Cacheble annotation work?

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, java-annotations

I was looking into annotations but wasn't able to grasp how annotations actually work. So I tried to break my problem as follows:

1. Lets suppose I have a spring boot project that is used as a dependency in various applications.
2. I annotate one of its methods with @Cacheble called Cached() and generate its jar.
3. I create a new project which includes the above project as dependency and uses the method Cached() and itself have various caches for its own caching.
4. Further, I enable LTW in this project.

Now, how would the whole annotation processing happen in this case?

Thanks,
Stotra

Comment: Too little information. Does the other project use Spring? Why do you use LTW instead of proxies? An annotation by itself doesn't do anything it is just metadata without something to handle it it is useless.

Comment: Sorry, updated it more, let me know more details that must be required here.

Comment: Yes both will be spring boot, LTW is used (I just chose this to understand what happens in this case).

Comment: The annotation is spring boot's @Cacheable annotation.